# How to get difference between 1 Timestamp and 1 dateTime in minute or day

Tags: flutter, dart, datetime, timestamp

using DateTime we can use the following to get the difference

```
DateTime myFirstDateTime = DateTime.now();
DateTime mySecondtDateTime = DateTime.now();
myFirstDateTime.difference(mySecondtDateTime).inMinutes // or inDay
```

the previous code is working as expected but how can I handle the same between `Timestamp` and `DateTime` ?

I used the following but it give wrong result and strange negative numbers like -5623

```
Timestamp myTimestamp = // here I get the value from my Firebase field 
DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.now();

then I convert it `toDate()`
myDateTime.difference(myTimestamp.toDate()).inMinutes; //or inDay  

//output strange value
```

How can I do it? Thanks

Comment: Maybe check your brackets, they seem funky in the last line

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You might have to move the brackets as follows:

```
myDateTime.difference(myTimestamp.toDate()).inMinutes;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this one out

```
var myTimestamp = // here you get the value from your Firebase field 
DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.now();
DateTime myFirebaseTime = DateTime.parse(myTimestamp.toDate().toString()); 
myDateTime.difference(myFirebaseTime).inDays;
```